# create trigger insert update delete in 1 syntax

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

This is my syntax in oracle, can anybody help to convert it to mysql ??

```
CREATE trigger trigger_name  
before INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON xxx
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
IF INSERT THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG( nik, date_log, action, table) 
    VALUES ( 62057, NOW( ) ,  'insert', 'xxx') ;
ELSEIF UPDATE THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG( nik, date_log, action, table) 
    VALUES ( 62057, NOW( ) ,  'edit', 'xxx') ;
ELSEIF DELETE THEN
    INSERT INTO LOG( nik, date_log, action, table) 
    VALUES ( 62057, NOW( ) ,  'delete', 'xxx') ;
END IF;
END ;
```

Comment: You have to create different trigger for each action.Read MySql Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, we can add three separate trigger object: one to be fired for INSERT, one to be fired for UPDATE and another to be fired for DELETE.

Here's an example "before insert" trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
BEFORE INSERT ON xxx
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO log(nik, date_log, action, `table`) 
   VALUES (62057, NOW(),'insert','xxx');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

(I believe `TABLE` is a reserved word in MySQL, so the column name `table` will need to be escaped. The normative pattern is to use backticks around the identifier.)

We'd follow the same pattern to create the two other triggers, a BEFORE UPDATE trigger and a BEFORE DELETE trigger.