# Audit Log Script using Triggers

Tags: mysql

Audit Logs for 50 tables need to insert in one table called audit table whatever the event performed on the tables(insert,update,delete) occurs it should contain new_val,old_val and table name,class name,modified by like these fields into my Audit Table.50 tables data should contain only in one single table called Audit Table

It is showing that i need to write script for every table how many tables it contains

Comment: And what's your question? If you want to know whether you need a trigger per table, then the answer is yes, you need not just one, but three triggers per table (insert / update / delete). Since triggers and stored procs called by triggers cannot use dynamic sql, you have to write separate scripts for each table.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use triggers on your other tables to insert rows into your audit log table, you will indeed need to write three triggers for each table. (ON INSERT, ON UPDATE, ON DELETE).

Pain in the xxx. Triple pain in the xxx.  Sigh.

If this were my project I'd consider writing a program to query `information_schema.TABLES` for a list of the tables involved, and generate the CREATE TRIGGER code for the tables involved. But, depending on the complexity of your table structure, that might be more trouble than it's worth.

Maybe helpful: [create trigger insert update delete in 1 syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313722/create-trigger-insert-update-delete-in-1-syntax)

Comment: Can you call a procedure from a trigger?